# get Warning on WPML plugin functions-string-translation.php on line 304

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WPML plugin (Version: 2.0.4.1) in my WordPress(Version 3.5.1) site, but when I try to activate Twenty Eleven Theme, after that get this warnings.

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:.....\wp-content\plugins\sitepress-multilingual-cms\inc\functions-string-translation.php on line 304
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:.....\wp-content\plugins\sitepress-multilingual-cms\inc\functions-string-translation.php on line 304

Comment: I'm afraid this information is not enough. Check if [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) gives you additional info. Also, try to download a brand new copy of TwentyEleven. It's kind of weird because it's a well stablished plugin and a core theme. Maybe other plugin is interfering? See: [troubleshooting](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list).

Answer (score 0):

WPML 2.0.4.1 is really not supposed to work on WordPress 3.5. It was released before WordPress 3.2 existed. Since then, we've made over 1000 changes to WPML including numerous compatibility updates and bug fixes.

I know that this doesn't solve the problem you're facing, but I'm trying to explain that you're trying to get a very old version to work where it's most likely not going to work.